# Analysis Services - Create Date/Time dimension

Tags: date, service, ssas, analysis, dimension

I am learning SSAS and trying to create a date dimension, but somehow it is not working for me.

This is the dimension structure
[image: This is the dimension structure]

This is the attribute relationship
[image: This is the attribute relationship]

As you can see here, when I tried to browse it, the "Fiscal Quarter" "Month", they are not grouped, they are listed one by one with the "Date"
[image: As you can see here, when I tried to browse it, the "Fiscal Quarter" "Month", they are not grouped, they are listed one by one with the "Date"]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay attention to the columns you configure as KeyColum and NameColumn.

Just things with the same KeyColumn are grouped together. Probably you have set the date as a key for all attributes.